# Flutter: the plugin requires Android SDK version 31 but it is set to 31?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am tryng to run: flutter build apk --release

The warnings and errors:

```
Warning: The plugin camera_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin connectivity_plus requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_core requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_crashlytics requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_messaging requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin firebase_performance requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_email_sender requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_local_notifications requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin image_picker_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin local_auth_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin path_provider_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin shared_preferences_android requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
Warning: The plugin sqflite requires Android SDK version 31.
For more information about build configuration, see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to E:\Work\swietelsky\client\ink-mobile\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  ...
}
```

As you can see I set it already, it was set even before:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my-application-id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

As you can see SDK installed: [image]

I need advices... Thanks.

Comment: Not sure but try updating the min sdk version to 21

Comment: Done that too, same results.

Comment: `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and then `Invalidate and Restart` can sometime help in cases where everything should be correct but you get strange errors like this

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to change the `targetSdkVersion` and it worked.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- Change this
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
build and check again.

Comment: I did this around 9584 times in the last 3 days. No success.

Comment: Is your  flutter version is latest ? You can try flutter pub update also

Comment: I did that too a lot of times.